# Working on writing a fugue exposition

Tags: composition, fugue

I am trying to write a fugue exposition in F minor with 3 voices. However, I don't succeed in rewriting the counter-subject in the tonic key. More generally, I was wondering what are the main issues in my attempt.

[image]

[Audio](https://vocaroo.com/1b57Kni8xoUc)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because these kinds of composition evaluations should be asked in [The Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium).